# Replace array php

Tags: php, arrays

```
[lang_1] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [answer] => satu
                [status_answer] => 2
                [key_array] => 0
                [language] => lang_1
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [answer] => dua_en
                [status_answer] => 3
                [key_array] => 
                [language] => lang_1
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [answer] => lima
                [status_answer] => 3
                [key_array] => 
                [language] => lang_1
            )

        [3] => Array
            (
                [answer] => enam
                [status_answer] => 3
                [key_array] => 
                [language] => lang_1
            )

    )

[lang_2] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [answer] => satu
                [status_answer] => 3
                [key_array] => 
                [language] => lang_2
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [answer] => dua_en
                [status_answer] => 2
                [key_array] => 1
                [language] => lang_2
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [answer] => lima
                [status_answer] => 3
                [key_array] => 
                [language] => lang_2
            )

        [3] => Array
            (
                [answer] => enam
                [status_answer] => 3
                [key_array] => 
                [language] => lang_2
            )

    )
```

I have this two array. My problem is, how i can replace array in `lang_1` with array in `lang_2` where  `status_answer = 2` only

Comment: What if there are multiple elements in `lang_2` where `status_answer = 2`?

Comment: That will not happen.. But if happen. Just take the value in lang_2. Just want to replace from lang_2 to lang_1

Comment: So write a loop that finds the element in `lang_2` that has the value you want. Then write a loop that finds the element in `lang_1` that you want to replace, and replace it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First search `lang_2` for the element you want:

```
foreach ($array['lang_2'] as $el) {
    if ($el['status_answer'] == 2) {
        $replacement = $el;
        break;
    }
}
```

Then search `lang_1` for the element you want to replace:

```
foreach ($array['lang_1'] as &$el) {
    if ($el['status_answer'] == 2) {
        $el = $replacement;
    }
}
```